# alias to chrome console.log

Tags: javascript, exception, google-chrome

I would like to know why the follow code doesn't work in the Google Chrome:

```
// creates a xss console log

var cl = ( typeof( console ) != 'undefined' ) ? console.log : alert;
cl('teste');
```

output: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

thanks.

Comment: I just ran across a similar problem, where I wanted to override the `console.log` method (to catch and send output). My solution was to declare the alias on the `console` object. Roughly: `console.__log = console.log;console.log = function(){__console.log.apply(console, arguments);};`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you write `cl();`, you're calling `log` in the global context.

Chrome's `console.log` doesn't want to be called on the `window` object.

Instead, you can write

```
cl = function() { return console.log.apply(console, arguments); };
```

This will call `log` in the context of `console`.

Comment: @augustowebd: For more about this "context" thing, I've written up a couple of blog posts that may be useful: *[Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)* and *[You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)*

Comment: This has the drawback of not logging the correct line number in Web Inspector.

Answer (score 31):

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-bugs/gGVPJ1T-qA0/F8uSupbO2R8J

Apparently you can also defined log:

```
 log = console.log.bind(console);
```

and then the line numbers also work

Comment: I love you, this has been driving me nuts for years

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately @SLaks answer isnt applied to IE because it uses window-object as context in console.log-method.

I would be suggest another way that doesnt depend on browser:

```
!window.console && (console = {});

console.debug = console.debug || $.noop;
console.info = console.info || $.noop;
console.warn = console.warn || $.noop;
console.log = console.log || $.noop;

var src = console, desc = {};
desc.prototype = src;
console = desc;

desc.log = function(message, exception) {
    var msg = message + (exception ? ' (exception: ' + exception + ')' : ''), callstack = exception && exception.stack;
    src.log(msg);
    callstack && (src.log(callstack));
    //logErrorUrl && $.post(logErrorUrl, { message: msg + (callstack || '') }); // Send clientside error message to serverside.
};
```