# IE 11 - console.log is displaying undefined for object properties

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console.log

This is a pretty short example. I copy and paste the code below into a file, save it, and open it. Works fine in Chrome, fails in ie 11.

The output on the console is nonsense!
What's going on? Have a stumbled upon some strange bug?

test.b is clearly not undefined, as it is accessible by the JSON parser and by direct object evaluation.

Also, switching around the order of the variables in the log function does nothing to change test.b being undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>wtf</title>
   <script>
      var test = {a:1,b:{c:1}}
      console.log(test,JSON.stringify(test),test.b);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    WTF IE
</body>
</html>
```

[image: nonsense]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in IE11. What is the specific version you're running?

Comment: 64 bit windows 7
11.0.9600.17239
I'm able to reproduce on my wife's computer.

Comment: Hmm, that appears to be a slightly newer version than I'm using (my minor version is 17126) so maybe it's a bug?

Comment: It only started an hour or two ago. It was literally working fine, and then I refreshed the page, and then it's not working anymore.

Comment: Maybe you're seeing the effects of corrupted memory? Tried restarting your machine?

Comment: I did. As I said before though, I'm able to reproduce on another computer. Very unlikely to be a memory corruption issue.

Comment: I tried here on my IE 11. Its "undefined"... tried the same on Chrome and FF and i found it to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue as well.

The issue was that the page i was working on had compatibility mode set to IE8.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

I believe IE8 did not have console, so console.log would be undefined.

Comment: I gave a complete example source file in my question. X-UA-Compatible was not defined, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own recursive log function, because the browser only logs on the first level.
To log all by default would cost too much performance and memory for the browser.
See: [recursive log function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876911/adding-depth-parameter-to-console-log-for-recursion)

Comment: Except it worked before hand just fine...

And it works just fine when manually using console.log from within the console...