# How can I use a Chrome browser extension to monitor and parse the output in the devtools console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am building a chrome extension that is supposed to aid in the debugging of software that runs on top of a website. This software can have a debug mode enabled that will cause a lot of output to the console using `console.log`.

I want to use my chrome extension to parse the console messages and show the important events in the UI for quicker debugging. However, I am not seeing a way to simply do this with [the API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools). Is there something I am missing? Should I override the `console.log` function? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods.

- Override console.log, console.warn, and so on, in [page context](/a/9517879) (this is important!). There are lots of examples (here's a [random one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559725/extending-console-log-without-affecting-log-line)). In your case it'll be even simpler as you'll just call the original method and transfer the arguments via CustomEvent to your content script ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198)), which will accumulate them.
- Use [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API with [Console.messageAdded](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Console/#event-messageAdded) or [Runtime.consoleAPICalled](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#event-consoleAPICalled) events. This will show a message bar in the entire browser about debugger being active unless you hide it globally by running chrome with `--silent-debugger-extension-api` command line, but that's somewhat dangerous if you accidentally install a malicious extension that uses chrome.debugger API.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I appreciate the examples and it's cool to hear I was on the right track.