# How to extend console.log which can accept args without using additional ()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bind, console.log, javascript-debugger

I've been working on extending `console.log` to make a colorful one that **keeps the stack trace** as to where it has been called. I've tried some solutions, but finally reach this point:

```js
const colorizedLog = (text, color= "#40a7e3", ...args) =>
  console.log.bind(
    console,
    `%c ${text}`,
    `font-weight:bold; color:${color}`,
    ...args
  );
colorizedLog("Title:", "#40a7e3", "This is a working example")();
```

With this little `binding`, we will be able to keep the stack trace, but the problem here is we have to use it with an annoying extra `()` at the end, because of returning value is the function itself which is the result of `bind`:

```js
 colorizedLog(
    "Title:",
    "info",
    "This is a working example")();
```

The top other resources that I've read through are as below:

1. [Extending console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559725/extending-console-log-without-affecting-log-line)
2. [Macro using babel- kent.c dodds](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros)
3. [Webpack Define plugin](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros)

#### Check Stack trace

```js
// useAppVersion.ts

export enum ColorStatus {
  info = "#40a7e3",
  ServerInfo = "#3e618a",
  warning = "#f28021",
  danger = "#b41e4a",
  dark = "#222222",
}
export const colorizedLog = (
  text: string,
  status: keyof typeof ColorStatus = "dark",
  ...args: any
) =>
  console.log.bind(
    console,
    `%c ${text}`,
    `font-weight:bold; color: ${ColorStatus[status]}`,
    ...args
  );

export const colorizedLog2 = (...args: any) => colorizedLog(...args)();
```

```js
// log.ts
console.log("console.log:", "Text");
colorizedLog("colorizedLog:", "dark", "Text")();
colorizedLog2("colorizedLog2:", "dark", "Text");
```

**Chrome Console**

As You can see the last one's stack trace is not correct or what we want. How to make it work?
[image]

Comment: Very interesting. What is your build setup?

Comment: @Werlious, just simple vue(webpack based config(babel+ts))

Comment: If you could, could you add a trace to your code? ```function trace() { try { throw new Error('trace');  }  catch(e) { alert(e.stack); }
}``` and then call `trace()` from each of those functions and post the output?

Comment: @Werlious, thanks, I've been used it before, but the problem will be an unnecessary list of stack traces that will be print, which we really don't  need them and the output will be polluted by them.

Comment: not a problem, but I really only mentioned it so we can have some track traces to see where the scope is being lost at, because I'm not sure if Chrome or Typescript is responsible

Answer (score 1):

You can make it immediately invoked:

```
const colorizedLog = (text, color= "#40a7e3", ...args) =>
  console.log.bind(
    console,
    `%c ${text}`,
    `font-weight:bold; color:${color}`,
    ...args
  )();

colorizedLog("Title:", "#40a7e3", "This is a working example");
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, we will lose the stack trace.

Comment: Since op already uses a lambda, I thought it is weird that op use a bind. This is even worse (both in functionality and readability) than my direct solution (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66182606/how-to-extend-console-log-which-can-accept-args#comment117007654_66182606))

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind adding another call to that stack trace, you can wrap it in another function that hides the extra `()`:

```
const rawColorizedLog = (
  text: string,
  status: keyof typeof ColorStatus = "dark",
  ...args: any
) =>
  console.log.bind(
    console,
    `%c ${text}`,
    `font-weight:bold; color: ${ColorStatus[status]}`,
    ...args
  );
export const colorizedLog = (...args: any) => rawColorizedLog(...args)();
```

Then you can just call `colorizedLog(...whatever)` but you will have an extra call to `rawColorizedLog` in the stack, but I'm sure you can think of a clever name for `rawColorizedLog` to cover up the extra call with something cooler ;)

Comment: We will lose the stack trace clicking in chrome.