# How to draw attention to errors in the console in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Sometimes developers on my team work with their console / dev tools window closed, and therefore miss key Next.js or React Js error and warning messages in the console.

I've tried overriding console.error and console.warn to prepend text into our app, only when the URL includes 'localhost', in hopes that I could draw attention to these errors, but it's not working reliably.

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const url = window.location.href;
      if (url.match(/localhost/i)) {
        // define a new console
        function buildDevConsole(oldCons) {
          return {
            log: function(text){
                oldCons.log(text);
                // Your code
            },
            info: function (text) {
                oldCons.info(text);
                // Your code
            },
            warn: function (text) {
                oldCons.warn(text);

                const pre = document.createElement("pre");
                pre.textContent = text;
                document.body.prepend(pre);
            },
            error: function (text) {
                oldCons.error(text);

                const pre = document.createElement("pre");
                pre.textContent = text;
                document.body.prepend(pre);
            }
          };
        }
        window.console = buildDevConsole(window.console);
      }
    }
  }, []);
// ... rest of function omitted
```

Is anyone aware of a way to know that errors or warnings are occuring with the console closed, during localhost `next dev` development?

### EDIT (19-Oct-2022)

One workaround is to let a chrome extension help with this. I've asked our team to install a plugin such as "Chrome JS Error Icon", which is one of many choices for things that proactively tell you that you should open your console. This extension can be restricted to localhost only in the extension settings.

I still would love a solution that works for modern browsers to somehow inject these into the page, but it's proving to be less reliable than I had hoped, for unknown reasons. (specifically, warnings will come into the page after a hard refresh, but not errors, with my implementation shown above).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559725/extending-console-log-without-affecting-log-line this helps?

Comment: Thanks, but I think I agree with the poster's edited question on the link above, which ends with: "the desired functionality is NOT achievable in the current versions of browsers".