# Abbreviating console.log in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [alias to chrome console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133649/alias-to-chrome-console-log)

This is really silly, but I can't abbreviate console.log (I'm using Chrome). Here's my naive attempt:

```
var log = console.log;
log("Bingo");  // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Should I be using apply()? But then I'd have to pass along the arguments, right?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This fails because references to Javascript methods do not include a reference to the object itself. A simple and correct way to assign the method `console.log` to a variable, and have the call apply to `console`, is to use the `bind` method on the `log` method, passing `console` as the argument:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
```

There is a hidden `this` argument to every method, and because of arguably bad language design, it's not closured when you get a reference to a method. The `bind` method's purpose is to preassign arguments to functions, and return a function that accepts the rest of the arguments the function was expecting. The first argument to `bind` should always be the `this` argument, but you can actually assign any number of arguments using it.

Using `bind` has the notable advantage that you don't lose the method's ability to accept more arguments. For instance, `console.log` can actually accept an arbitrary number of arguments, and they will all be concatenated on a single log line.

Here is an example of using `bind` to preassign more arguments to `console.log`:

```
var debugLog = console.log.bind(console, "DEBUG:");
```

Invoking `debugLog` will prefix the log message with `DEBUG:`.

Comment: +1 for explaining **why**, not just **how**.

Comment: This will not working < IE9, because console.log is a Host object, not an instance of Function. Therefore, console.log does not have a "bind" method. This will cause headache.

Comment: Incidentally, with ES6/ES7, you'll be able to do `::console.log` to have a log bound to console.

Answer (score 16):

The simple way will be to wrap it in a function:

```
var log = function (l) {
   console.log(l);
}
```

But make note that console.log can take an unlimited number of arguments so the appropriate way will be do this:

```
var l = function () {
   console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

Comment: This is the preferred solution.

Comment: @TaylorMac Why ?

Comment: `let log = (...l) => console.log(...l);` in es6 to keep multiple variables.