# Bind event handler to "console.log" JavaScript event

Tags: javascript

My script sends text to the console output from several places in Javascript (see examples), how do I bind an event handler function to the log function itself so that a function is executed each time the event is triggered?

```
try {
    //some code
} catch(e) {
    console.log("error: "+e)
}

function x(n) {
    //some code
    console.log(str)
}
```

Comment: Write an event binding and have `console.log("Some message");` in the function?

Comment: Redefine the log function to trigger an event you can bind a handler to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would override `console.log` (but store it in a different variable, in case we want to use it) like so:

```
var nativeLog = console.log.bind(console) //store native function

console.log = function(text){ //override
    nativeLog("<<<" + text)
}
```

[Abbreviating console.log in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944987/abbreviating-console-log-in-javascript)

Comment: You can create a new event that gets trigger from the overridden console.log, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/SzE34/

Comment: @towr - that would be an illegal invocation of the function you're currently overwriting.

Comment: @adeneo I don't quite understand what you mean, though I figure it has to  do with the (probably better) way TastySpaceApple stores the native function? My intent was more to add an `event` to the mix, though. --- Firefox didn't complain, but if you can give me some pointers to better my javascript I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @towr - chrome does throw an "illegal invocation" error, and using bind() would be better, otherwise the example of creating an event and triggering it is spot on, and surely the way to do it.