# What does this statement do? console.log.bind(console)

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript and getting a problem with the statement

```
console.log.bind(console)
```

Please tell me what does this statement actually do. I have applied this several times but it did not do anything.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723602/bind-event-handler-to-console-log-javascript-event

Comment: Function.bind() is missing from IE8, but should work fine in real browsers. post the broken code if in doubt.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` within a function call is determined by *how* the function is called (for normal functions, see * below). If it's called as part of an expression retrieving an object property (e.g., `foo.bar()` calls `bar()` as part of a property retrieval operation getting it from `foo`), `this` is set to the object that the property came from during the call to the function.

Suppose you wanted a shorter form of `console.log`, like `f`. You might do this:

```
var f = console.log; // <== Suspect!
```

...but if the `log` function relies on `this` referring to the `console` object during the call, then calling `f("Message here")` won't work, because `this` won't refer to `console`.

`Function#bind` is for just that situation: It lets you create a new function that, when called, will call the original with `this` set to the value you give. So

```
var f = console.log.bind(console); // Still suspect, for a different reason
```

...*should*, in theory, give you a function, `f`, that you can call to log to the console.

**Except**: Host-provided functions like `console.log` (and `alert` and `getElementById`) aren't required to be "real" JavaScript functions (although on modern browsers they tend to be, or at least very close), and aren't required to have all of their features, inculding `bind`. So if you're getting an error on that line, it may be that the engine you're using that line on doesn't support `bind` on the `console.log` function.

So what are "host-provided functions"? Any function not explicitly defined in the specification as being part of *JavaScript*, the language. So again, on a browser that's browser-related functions like `alert` or `console.log` and such.

I can think of two reasons that line might be giving you trouble:

1. The above: You're using a JavaScript engine that doesn't make `console.log` a real function.
2. You're using the line above on IE with the Dev Tools closed. On IE when the dev tools aren't open, the `console` object isn't defined, and so that line will throw a `ReferenceError`.

If the end goal is to get a function you can call, say `f("Message here")`, for `console.log`, here's how you can do that dealing with both #1 and #2 above:

```
function f(item) {
    if (typeof console != "undefined" && console.log) {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

That only lets you give one item, whereas `console.log` lets you give multiple items (`console.log("this", "that", "and the other")`), but if `console.log` may not be a real JavaScript function, then it may not have `Function#apply`, which makes it very hard to wrap it.

Now, if you don't care about getting the *same* output you'd get from `console.log("this", "that", "and the other")` so long as you can see what's there, simply use `console.log(arguments);` (`arguments` is the built-in identifier for all arguments passed into a function). But if you want to replicate the exact output, you end up doing something like this:

```
function f() {
    var a = arguments;

    if (typeof console != "undefined" && console.log) {
        if (console.log.apply) {
            // It has Function#apply, use it
            console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        } else {
            // Ugh, no Function#apply
            switch (a.length) {
                case 0: console.log(); break;
                case 1: console.log(a[0]); break;
                case 2: console.log(a[0], a[1]); break;
                case 3: console.log(a[0], a[1], a[2]); break;
                case 4: console.log(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]); break;
                case 5: console.log(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]); break;
                default:
                    throw "f() only supports up to 5 arguments";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and that's just ugly.

---

* ES5 added *bound functions*, which are functions that have their `this` value attached to them via binding:

```
// Normal function
function foo() {
    console.log(this.name);
}

// Create a bound function:
var f = foo.bind(someObject);
```

It doesn't matter how you call `f`, it will call `foo` with `this` set to `someObject`.

* ES2015 (aka ES6) added *arrow functions*. With arrow functions, `this` is **not** set by how the function is called; instead, the function inherits `this` from the context in which it was created:

```
// Whatever `this` is here...
var f = () => {                             // <== Creates an arrow function
    // Is what `this` will be here
};
```

Arrow functions are really handy when you're doing something like `Array#forEach` within an object method:

```
this.counter = 0;
this.someArray.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.has(/* some relevant something */)) {
        ++this.counter;
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! People obviously like this answer but I can't see how it answers the OP question? Maybe I'm just being stupid but it seems to be banging on about a bunch of stuff peripheral to the actual question (as do the other answers).

Comment: @geoidesic: It directly answers the question: *"So `var f = console.log.bind(console);` should, in theory, give you a function, `f`, that you can call to log to the console."* It also explains why it does that, why you need to do that rather than just `var f = console.log` (which is where `this` comes into it), and how it may or may not work depending on the host implementation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for the answer. I am using `console.log.bind` in Typescript/Angular for a logger, to print stuff in console with the link to the class where the logger was called instead of inside the Logger class itself, like without `bind`. Unfortunately I cannot pass a second parameter to bind, e.g. `console.log.bind(console, 'background: #222; color: #bada55');` will simply print the second argument as a string and not apply it to console. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Phil maybe I'm confused, but are you expecting it to apply those styles to the console output? That's not how it works. What you have is roughly equivalent to `(...args) => console.log('background: #222; color: #bada55', ...args)`. That is, it just uses that css string as the first argument to `console.log` in any invocations of your new *bound* function. I don't think you're gonna be able to use `bind` to achieve what you want. That's just not quite how that console.log styling works. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017382/363701

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You mention `...but if the log function relies on this referring to the console object during the call, then calling f("Message here") won't work, because this won't refer to console.`. Is there any such case (where the log relies on this to be console) that can be demonstrated or referred to?

Comment: @KostasX - I vaguely recall that some earlish implementation of `console` didn't like it when `log` was called with `this` not referring to `console`, but I don't recall which one. I doubt any modern one cares, not least because I see it used without worrying about `this` a fair bit.

Answer (score 14):

Quick update on this matter, **it seems that you don't need to bind the console to itself anymore.**

Chromium started rolling out some deep changes on the `console` object, which is now already bound to itself. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/807ec9550e8a31517966636e6a5b506474ab4ea9

It also seems that all the other browsers have followed this path (tested on recent version of Firefox and in Node).

I guess, if you need to be compatible with old browsers, you would still need to manually bind the console, but for debug purposes, you can now omit the `.bind(console)` :)

Answer (score 7):

T.J. Crowder's answer helped me explain and solve a problem I had with redirecting `console.log` output, but his solution for the "no Function#apply" case seemed arbitrarily limiting for many use-cases.

I rewrote his code like this which is a little cleaner and more functional:

```
function f() {
    var a = arguments;

    if (typeof console != "undefined" && console.log) {
        if (console.log.apply) {
            // It has Function#apply, use it
            console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        } else {
            // Ugh, no Function#apply
            var output = '';
            for (i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
                output += arguments[i] + ' ';
            }
            console.log(output);
        }
    }
}
```

`console.log` separates arguments with a space, so I replicated that here as well. The primary limitation for this is that it does not handle arguments that are objects. You can stringify those if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, it gives the `console.error` function as the error handler, and `bind(console)` makes it use the `console` as the value of `this` within it's body. Otherwise, `this` would be set to a global object (`window` in browsers) and the call would fail. Well explained [here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/12/29/console-error-bind/).

Often you can see this in `Promise` error handling (for example, from the Angular 2 quickstart):

```
System.import("unmarshaller/Unmarshaller.js").then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

*The offtopic part:*

You may want to create your own handler to pre-process the error. In the above example, `console.error` prints ugly `Error` in the console because `SystemJS` only tells that *"Error loading Unmarshaller.js"*. And the other error is hidden in `originalErr`.

Make a custom handler to unwrap:

```
function handleError(e) {
    if (e.originalErr)
        throw e.originalErr;
    throw e;
}

System.import("unmarshaller/Unmarshaller.js").then(null, handleError);
```

No need for `.bind()`, and will give you the `Error` originally thrown, like:

> Error: Given object doesn't specify "w:winduptype" and no target class given:
>     [{"w:winduptype":["FileResource","ArchiveModel:","WarArchiveModel"], ...

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an attempt to answer the question at all. It doesn't describe what `console.error.bind(console)` means, it only presents an alternative (which behaves differently in several significant ways) for a very specific usecase (which the question doesn't mention at all)..

Comment: That's your perception of the question, which itself is quite vague. There's no point in repeating the other answers. Changed to be more general, though.