# Why 'console.log.bind(console)' instead of just 'console.log' here?

Tags: javascript

In this [Blog article: "We have a problem with promises"](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html), I came upon this code snippet:

```
somePromise().then(function () {
  return anotherPromise();
}).then(function () {
  return yetAnotherPromise();
}).catch(console.log.bind(console)); // <-- this is badass
```

What puzzles me here is the last line, the 'badass' one. I had never had to use the 'bind' method anywhere up until now and am not really knowledgable in JavaScript. Having now just read about the [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in the Mozilla Developer Network docs, I understand that one can assign a different "this" object, to any function with it (and also hard-insert predefined arguments, so that they become 'non-arguments' to the returned function).

However, as far as I understand, `console.log.bind(console)` should be simply the same as `console.log`. What is the difference? What have I missed or misunderstood here, and why is this kind of construct used?

Thanks.

Comment: When you detach it from `console`, i.e. `var log = console.log;` and then call it as `log('derp');`, `this` will no longer refer to `console`. `bind` fixes that.

Comment: Duplicate question. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668759/what-does-this-statement-do-console-log-bindconsole

Comment: Thanks for explaining the gist @Siguza and for pointing to the already answered question @A Paul.
Very helpful.