# nightmare js console log something

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I have this code:

```
nightmare
  .goto('https://xxxdsfdx.com')
  .type('#ap_email', 'mail@gmail.com')
  .type('#ap_password', 'passsword')
  .click('#signInSubmit')
  .wait('#report-wrapper')
  .click('.a-tab-heading:nth-child(7)')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.a-box-inner'))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('failed:', error);
  });
```

I want to console.log contents of `.a-box-inner` div

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`.then(console.log.bind(console))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668759/what-does-this-statement-do-console-log-bindconsole

Comment: try to put `.end()` after the `evaluate`

Comment: it outputs empty object `{}`

Answer (score 1):

I should put innerHTML

```
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.a-box-inner')).innerHTMl
```