# Why does console.log need to be wrapped in a react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does console.log need to wrapped before I can use it in an event handler?

https://jsfiddle.net/7e5yLh63/17/

In the example above, this code does nothing (line 44-51) when I click 'Add':

```
function ManufacturerWrapper() {
  return <AddManufacturerForm onAddManufacturer={console.log} />
}
```

But when I change it to

```
function log(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

function ManufacturerWrapper() {
  return <AddManufacturerForm onAddManufacturer={log} />
}
```

It logs to the console as expected. Why can't I just pass in `console.log` directly? Why do I need to wrap it in my own function first?

I'm using Firefox if that matters

Comment: I’m not entirely sure, but passing `console.log.bind(console)` should work. If that’s the case, then the reason that `console.log` alone doesn’t work would be: it’s a method that depends on the `this` context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668759/what-does-this-statement-do-console-log-bindconsole

Comment: you mean change it to `onAddManufacturer={console.log.bind(console)}`? It doesn't result in printing in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You're probably asking for this:

```
onAddManufacturer={()=>console.log('log this!')}
```

Comment: That's another way of writing the same thing the OP has already found to solve the problem, only less efficient since a new function is generated each time the component renders … and it doesn't address the question of *Why*.