# How do you run functions from one function that's been passed inside another one?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function to time how long it takes other functions to run. The code works with some functions, but not others.

When it fails, the errors are like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.query is not a function
```

I've found the documentation for [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), and [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which talk about changing `this`. It seems like a solution is there, but I haven't been able to puzzle one out.

Here's a sample that demonstrates the issue. It's with lunr (via `npm install -D lunr`) in an Electron app. It's running in the index.html browser page with electron setup to allow node integration on that part of the app. I'd make it more generic, but I don't know how.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const lunr = require('lunr')

const timeFunctionExecution = (func, args) => {
    const t0 = performance.now()
    const payload = func(args)
    const t1 = performance.now()
    const time = t1 - t0

    const report = {
        "payload": payload, 
        "time": time
    }
    return report
}


function createLunrSearchIndex(contentDir) {

    const searchIndex = lunr(function () {
        this.ref('filename')
        this.field('content')

        let fileList = fs.readdirSync(contentDir)

        fileList.forEach(function(filename) {
            let content = fs.readFileSync(`${contentDir}/${filename}`, 'utf8')
            this.add(
                {
                   'filename': filename,
                    'content': content
                }
            )
        }, this)
    })

    return searchIndex
}


// This works and verifies the basic timer works
let report1 = timeFunctionExecution(createLunrSearchIndex, 'data')
console.log(report1)

// This works and verifies the search index works
let basicResults = report1.payload.search("chicken")
console.log(basicResults)

// Combine the two though, and it fails
let report2 = timeFunctionExecution(report1.payload.search, "chicken")
console.log(report2)
```

The first set of results from `timeFunctionExecution` work if you call them directly, but when I pass it through the `timeFunctionExecution` again, I get the error.

Inspecting the `console.log(report1)` call shows the query function exists

[image: console.log output showing the .query() function is available.]

`basicResults` has valid data so `.query()` would seem to be working in general but not when passed through the timing function.

Is there a way to pass functions like this while retaining the ability to call functions inside them (assuming that's the problem)?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a scoping problem? You can test that by replacing `function() {}` with `() => {}` everywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that `report1.payload` is an instance of the `lunr.Index` constructor (which may be a class, for example).

So, when you do something like this:

```
report1.payload.search("chicken");
```

You are calling the `search` method under the `report1.payload` instance, which is of type `lunr.Index`. The problem is that, when you pass an (unbound) reference to this function, it loses its context.

That means that when you do something like:

```
timeFunctionExecution(report1.payload.search, "chicken");
```

You just take a reference to the `search` function without any context. Think in context here as the implicit `this` parameter that the `search` method expects to receive.

So you have to options to fix this:

1. Pass a bound function reference (created using the `Function.prototype.bind` method)
2. Accept, from the `timeFunctionExecution` function, another argument to the `this` value

So, with a bound method, you may do something like (option 1 example):

```js
class Index {
  query(...args) {
    return { args };
  }
  search(...args) {
    return {
      context: this,
      // Notice that this method (`search`) requires a context
      // to work, as it depends on `query`, another method
      // that can only be accessed through `this`.
      queryResult: this.query(args)
    };
  }
}

function indirectCall(fn, argsArr = []) {
  const payload = fn(...argsArr);
  return payload;
}

const ins1 = new Index();
// Bound the function to the instance (`ins1`). No problems here.
console.log(indirectCall(ins1.search.bind(ins1), ['a', 'b']));

const ins2 = new Index();
// The function is not bound. An error will arise.
console.log(indirectCall(ins1.search, ['a', 'b']));
```

And with a new `thisArg` (option 2 example):

```js
class Index {
  query(...args) {
    return { args };
  }
  search(...args) {
    return {
      context: this,
      // Notice that this method (`search`) requires a context
      // to work, as it depends on `query`, another method
      // that can only be accessed through `this`.
      queryResult: this.query(args)
    };
  }
}

function indirectCall(fn, argsArr = [], thisArg = null) {
  const payload = fn.apply(thisArg, argsArr);
  return payload;
}

const ins1 = new Index();
// Given a `thisArg` (the instance).
console.log(indirectCall(ins1.search, ['a', 'b'], ins1));

const ins2 = new Index();
// The `thisArg` is not given. An error will arise.
console.log(indirectCall(ins1.search, ['a', 'b']));
```

You can learn more in [What does this statement do? `console.log.bind(console)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28668759/7445826) and in [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/7445826).