# Why can't I rename console.log?

Tags: javascript

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward:

```
var print = console.log;
print("something"); // Fails with Invalid Calling Object (IE) / Invalid Invocation (Chrome)
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [alias to chrome console.log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133649/alias-to-chrome-console-log)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Becase you are calling the method with the global object as the receiver while the method is strictly non-generic and requires exactly an instance of `Console` as the receiver.

An example of generic method is `Array.prototype.push`:

```
   var print = Array.prototype.push;
   print(3);
   console.log(window[0]) // 3
```

You can do something like this though:

```
var print = function() {
     return console.log.apply( console, arguments );
};
```

And ES5 provides `.bind` that also achieves the same as above:

```
var print = console.log.bind( console );
```

Comment: Awesome, I like the alternative.

Comment: Another solution (where `Function.prototype.bind` is available) would be `var print = console.log.bind(console);`

Comment: Note that either of these solutioms won't work with multiple arguments: `print('1', '2'); // "1"`